# Slick Carousel - Custom indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I need to create a slick slider with custom designed slider indicators and controls. The slider is on auto scroll and also is interactive to users' click and swipe. This [Pen](https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/aJKbVL?editors=1010) is a pretty accurate demo of what I have right now.

**Description**

I am using a Slick's `afterChange` function to calculate the index of the current active slide and then move the orange indicator along with the movement of each slide like so:

```
$('.about-slider-content').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, direction){
    var left_val, li_wid = parseInt($(".individual-indicators .slide").css("width"));
    var currentSlideIndex = $(".about-slider-content").slick("slickCurrentSlide");
    left_val = currentSlideIndex*li_wid+40;
    $(".about-active-indicator").animate({
        left: left_val
    });
    // left
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="about-slider">
  <ul class="about-slider-content">
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Industrial Machine Learning</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Industrial Operations and Reliability Experience</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Leverage your existing investments</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="about-slider-indicator">
    <span class="slider-arrow arrow-prev icon-arrow-left">
        <img src='https://image.ibb.co/h2WX0a/arrow_left.png'>
    </span>
    <!--<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>-->
    <ul class="individual-indicators">
      <span class="about-active-indicator"></span>
      <li class="slide" id="1"></li>
      <li class="slide" id="2"></li>
      <li class="slide" id="3"></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="slider-arrow arrow-next icon-arrow-right">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bESGRF/arrow_right.png" alt="arrow_right" border="0">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Issue**

You can notice on checking out my pen than the movement of the orange slider indicator is not in sync with the movement of each slide. The indicator is a few milliseconds slower or more succinctly put, the indicator moves only **after** the slides have changed. I have tried using Slick's `beforeChange` method but  in that case the slider indicator doesn't move on the first slide change at all and also the ordering of the slides change.

**What do I want**

- The slide indicator needs to move in sync with the movement of the slides i.e the indicator has to change position as each slide is changing. something like this [site](https://www.sweetpunk.com/)
- any way to make the slide indicator draggable i.e. clicking and dragging the indicator would change the slides appropriately. something like this [site](http://www.thieb.co/)

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `beforeChange` event, in fact, the event handler actually exposes the current and next slide indexes, so you do not need to call the `.slick()` method again just to access the index, i.e.

```
$('.about-slider-content').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, direction){
    var currentSlideIndex = $(".about-slider-content").slick("slickCurrentSlide");

    // Rest of your code...
});
```

...can simply be refactored into:

```
$('.about-slider-content').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var currentSlideIndex = nextSlide;

    // Rest of your code...
});
```

The next part of the solution is simply to set the cardinal coordinate, `left`, using `.css()` instead of using `.animate()`. The transitions are already handled by CSS transitions so there is really no need to use jQuery to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
$(".about-active-indicator").css({
    left: left_val
});
```

If you want to perfectly synchronise the speed, just remember to set the CSS transition duration to be the same as the slide speed/transition duration.

You can see the proof-of-concept example in the code snippet below (the CSS is simply copied from the compiled SASS from your pen without any further modification). I have also forked your Pen and fixed it: http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/QpxgYy?editors=0010

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var aboutSlider = $('.about-slider-content');
 $('.about-slider-content').slick({
  // dots: true
  infinite: true,
  arrows: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  mobileFirst: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000
  // prevArrow: "<img src='https://image.ibb.co/h2WX0a/arrow_left.png'>",
  // nextArrow: "<img src='../img/background/arrow-right.png'>"
 });

 $(".arrow-next").on("click", function() {
  $('.about-slider-content').slick("slickNext");
  //$(".individual-indicators .slide").removeClass("about-slider-active");
  var currentSlideIndex = $(".about-slider-content").slick("slickCurrentSlide")
 });
 $(".arrow-prev").on("click", function() {
  $(".about-slider-content").slick("slickPrev");
  //$(".individual-indicators .slide").removeClass("about-slider-active");
  var currentSlideIndex = $(".about-slider-content").slick("slickCurrentSlide");
 });

 $('.about-slider-content').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var left_val, li_wid = parseInt($(".individual-indicators .slide").css("width"));
    var currentSlideIndex = nextSlide;
  //$(".individual-indicators .slide").removeClass("about-slider-active");
  //var currentSlideIndex = $("li.slick-acitve").attr('id');
  left_val = currentSlideIndex*li_wid+40;
  $(".about-active-indicator").css({
      left: left_val
     });
 });
})
```

```css
.about-slider-header {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.about-slider {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 17px 30px 17px;
}

.about-slider-content__header {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
}

.about-slider-content__description {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.slider-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.slide {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #adadad;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.about-slider-indicator {
  display: flex;
}

.about-slider-indicator .individual-indicators {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 7px auto 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.about-slider-indicator .individual-indicators .about-active-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f79237, #f3775a);
  top: -1px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
  left: 40px;
}

.about-slider-active {
  height: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

.about-slider-content li {
  cursor: grab;
}

.about-slider-content li:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.next-animation {
  transition: all 0.2 ease;
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

.prev-animation {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}

.slider-arrow {
  color: red;
  cursor: auto;
}

.slider-arrow-active {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<div class="about-slider">
  <ul class="about-slider-content">
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Industrial Machine Learning</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Industrial Operations and Reliability Experience</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4 class="about-slider-content__header bold-text">Leverage your existing investments</h4>
      <p class="description-text about-slider-content__description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="about-slider-indicator">
    <span class="slider-arrow arrow-prev icon-arrow-left">
        <img src='https://image.ibb.co/h2WX0a/arrow_left.png'>
    </span>
    <!--<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>-->
    <ul class="individual-indicators">
      <span class="about-active-indicator"></span>
      <li class="slide" id="1"></li>
      <li class="slide" id="2"></li>
      <li class="slide" id="3"></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="slider-arrow arrow-next icon-arrow-right">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bESGRF/arrow_right.png" alt="arrow_right" border="0">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would it be possible to add a drag functionality to the indicator?

Comment: @snow It is possible, but it's going to be quite complicated and probably better answered in a separate question. You'll have to snap the indicator to fixed positions, listen to dragging events and etc. This probably means using a styled input type range might be more appropriate.